# how to convert a value to integer type string?

Tags: c, printf

we all know that to convert a value in a string we can do following

```
char* buffer = ... allocate a buffer ...
int value = 4564;
sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
```

but what can we do if instead of character buffer i want to convert data to integer buffer, basically i want to do following

```
int* buffer = ... allocate a buffer ...
int value = 4564;
sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with buffer = &value?

Comment: @NedStark Because buffer will just be pointing to value, whereas the OP wants the data copied.

Comment: So you *don't* want the character representation of your integer; you want the *value* copied into a dynamic storage buffer, Is that correct ? (your question, and particularly the last line of code, is not entirely without haze). `int *pInt = malloc(sizeof(int)); *pInt = value;` ??

Comment: Do you want buffer to point to an array of integers, where at each index, you store a single digit of original number?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to define buffer as the value of 'value', and not a pointer to the address of 'value'. See below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* Allocate memory. */
    int* buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int value = 1000;

    /* Sets the number stored in buffer equal to value. */
    *buffer = value;

    /* prints 1000 */
    printf("%d\n", *buffer);

    /* Change value to show buffer is not pointing to the address of 'value'. */
    value = 500;

    /* Still prints 1000. If we had used 
    int* buffer = &value, it would print 500. */
    printf("%d\n", *buffer);

    return 0;
}
```